# Web Part Inside ASCX Page

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to include multiple web part in ASCX page. My ASCX page is very simple and it only includes tabbed navigations, inside those tabs I would like to embed web parts. Code below does not work, any suggestions.

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%"> 
                <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1"><span>Weather</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Stock</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are no web parts nor even zones in the sample code so it is hard to tell why it is not working

Comment: Do you mean ASPX, or are you really creating a user control? In that case, you should review your design because this might not be the best option for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no zones.
2. You can't put zones in a ascx page
3. Yes you can put webparts in your ascx, but they are going to be static. Meaning you cannot edit them in edit mode on your website. You need configurate them in the source code.

This can be done by using SharePoint Designer, inserting a webpart to a pagelayout and configure it there, then go to *Code* view and copy the html and then paste it into your .ascx page.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use tabs, its good to go for a lightweight html control. Checkout the jquery tab plugin : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

You can easily edit the markup and can insert webpart zones where needed.
Then you can add your webparts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add webparts to a static aspx page, you'll have to register the webpart control on top, then put the control where you want.  Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab(v=vs.100).aspx

I'm pretty sure this should work for webparts.

Answer (score 0):

Every visual web part uses some ascx control. It is located in Program files...  \ControlTemplates\FeatureName\WebPartName\WebPartName.ascx . Therefore you can use not webpart but ascx control from this web part.

Hope it will help you.